# How to change field width in LayoutView devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

Have an Xtragrid and LayoutView (layoutView1) in it. I have attached a simple object, each propertie of my object is represented by a row. How can I set the row width as wide as I want it to be?

Add.: VS 2010, DXperience 12.2

```
public partial class Form1 : XtraForm
{
        //MyForm ctor
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AddColumn("First");
            AddColumn("Second");

            List<Datas> d = new List<Datas>();
            d.Add(new Datas());
            gridControl1.DataSource = d;
        }

        void AddColumn(String fieldName)
        {
            Byte colNum = (Byte)(layoutView1.Columns.Count % columns);
            LayoutViewColumn column = layoutView1.Columns.AddField(fieldName);

            column.Caption = fieldName;
            column.Name = "ColumnName_" + fieldName;

            column.LayoutViewField.Name = "layoutViewField_" + fieldName ;

            // What should I do with *.Size to make work? 
            //Now it takes a row from border to border in any case
            column.LayoutViewField.Size = new Size(100, 20);
            column.LayoutViewField.MaxSize = new Size(100, 20);
        }
    }

    //Simple class for tests
    public class Datas
    {
        public String First { get; set; }
        public String Second { get; set; }

        public Datas()
        {
            First = "One";
            Second = "Two";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main rule for the LayoutView card's layout - **items should occupy the entire card space**. You  can use the [EmptySpaceItem](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraLayoutEmptySpaceItemtopic) to add empty space to a card.

It can be accomplished using the Layout Designer with easy:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with:
`layoutView1.BestFitColumns();`

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Layout.LayoutView' does not contain a definition for 'BestFitColumns' and no extension method 'BestFitColumns' accepting a first argument of type 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Layout.LayoutView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @MilenPavlov a `Layoutview` is not the same thing as a `Gridview`. Although they both inherits from `BaseView`.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
layoutView1.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = false;.
layoutView1.BestFitColumns()
```

Comment: 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Layout.LayoutView' does not contain a definition for 'BestFitColumns' and no extension method 'BestFitColumns' accepting a first argument of type 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Layout.LayoutView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Same thing with first row.